# How to temporarily turn off NetworkManager from the command-line?

Tags: network-manager

The network interface should not make a request for an IP over DHCP. So, what is the command to turn off NetworkManager in Ubuntu?

Update:

I am writing a script in which the interfaces receive static IPs. For this to happen I need to put a line in the script which will turn off NetworkManager. But when I'm not using that script I want to have DHCP on the interfaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to have your inteface make a DHCP request, simply edit it (right on network manager applet, choose "Edit Connections", click on the interface in question, then choose the IPv4 tab and change "Automatic (DHCP)" to "Manual" and specify your settings manually.

If you need to turn off network manager regardless, use

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

You can specify stop, start or restart for most services.

Htorque notes that service is being deprecated in Ubuntu in favour of the `stop`, `start` and `restart` commands.  So :

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

would also work.  I still prefer using service because, as of Maverick, there's no auto-complete when you use the newer commands.  A [bug has been filed about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/672067), and from that, a fix has been released, so hopefully this will be rectified in Natty this coming April.

Comment: I am writing a script in which the interfaces receive static ips. For this to happen I need to put a line in the script which will turn off the network manager. But when I'm not using that script I want to have dhcp on the interfaces.

Comment: Okay updated my answer.  You should really update your question with this specific requirement.

Comment: Addendum: `service` still works with Upstart, but it is a SysV command.

Comment: By which you mean that it will be phased out in favour of `stop` and `start`, right?  I'm surprised it doesn't offer deprecation warnings when you run it actually.

Answer (score 2):

I've recentely had a similar issue. For some reason, NetworkManager would default to DHCP even if I specify a static IP entry in NetworkManager or /etc/network/interfaces. I've solved it by uninstalling NetworkManager. If you want just to turn NetworkManager of *temporary*, run:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

Comment: A simpler solution might be to untick "Connect Automatically" in network manager for the interface affected.

Comment: I've had just one entry, the static one, which should connect automatically with the static IP settings.